# What kind of servers does Apple have in their NC datacenter?

Tags: apple-inc

Siri telling me more often than not that it is having trouble connecting got me wondering what kind of servers Apple is filling its datacenters with. At some point in the past, I'd have assumed Xserves running OSX Server, but given that they are no longer making Xserves (or at least they are not commercially available), I can't help picturing pallets of Dell servers being unloaded and racked at the North Carolina datacenter.

Is Apple running its datacenter on Linux or Windows? Are they using standard PC hardware from Dell or IBM or HP? Or have they continued to manufacture Xserves for their own use and have everything running Lion Server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't relate to a practical question to be solved as a user of Apple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following through from the Wheat's answer, comes [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/tale-of-two-data-center-strategies-apple-vs-facebook/50418?tag=content;siu-container) article which indicates that the datacenter contains a mix of "Mac OS X, IBM/AIX, Sun/Solaris, and Linux systems...Red Hat Linux and Oracle Enterprise Linux".

At least it is good to see that Dell isn't listed explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I have read that Apple uses [Microsoft Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/) and [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) as at least part of their software platform for iCloud. Sounds like heresy, but there appears to be [some evidence to support this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/is-apple-really-using-windows-azure-to-power-icloud/9687).